# Issues calling/passing template functions and variables

Tags: c++, templates

I am having issues calling a template function (removeStu()). When testing it without declaring it as a template function it works partly, but not to the extent I want it to. 
Here is the error message:

```
error: ‘removeStu’ was not declared in this scope
   removeStu(stuAr, count, key);
```

I do not have removeStu declared as a prototype and when I do I get these errors:

```
college.cpp:23:16: error: variable or field ‘removeStu’ declared void
 void removeStu(T1 stuAr[], int& count, const T2& key);
                ^

college.cpp:23:16: error: ‘T1’ was not declared in this scope
college.cpp:23:28: error: expected primary-expression before ‘int’
 void removeStu(T1 stuAr[], int& count, const T2& key);

college.cpp:23:40: error: expected primary-expression before ‘const’
 void removeStu(T1 stuAr[], int& count, const T2& key);
                                        ^

college.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
college.cpp:44:30: error: ‘removeStu’ was not declared in this scope
   removeStu(stuAr, count, key);
```

Here is my main where I call removeStu

```
int main()
{
  int count = 0; //the number of students in the array
  int curID = START; //curID is the student id used for the next student you creating
  student stuAr[SIZE];   //student array with constant size of 100

  cout << "====Student1====" << endl;
  addStu(stuAr, count, curID);   //adds student to array from input
  cout << "====Student2====" << endl;
  addStu(stuAr, count, curID);   //adds student to array from input
  cout << "====Student3====" << endl;
  addStu(stuAr, count, curID);   //adds student to array from input


  allStuInfo(stuAr, count);     //shows all info inside stuAr

  int key;
  cout << "Enter ID of student you wish to remove: ";
  cin >> key;
  removeStu(stuAr, count, key);

  allStuInfo(stuAr, count);     //shows all info inside stuAr


return 0;
}
```

Here is removeStu

```
template <class T1, class T2>
void removeStu(T1 ar[], int& n, const T2& id)   //case 3 from admissions
{
  string f, l;
  if(remove(ar, n, id))
    {
      id--;
      cout << f << " " << l << " has been removed." << endl;
    }
  else
    cout << "student with id " << id << " doesn't exist" << endl;
}
```

remove() function which is called by removeStu()

```
template <class T1, class T2>
bool remove(T1 ar[], int n, const T2& key)
{
  int temp = find(ar, n, key);
  if(temp == -1)
    {
      return false;
    }else
    {
      for (int temp; temp < n; ++temp)
        {
          ar[temp] = ar[temp + 1]; // copy next element left
        }
      return true;
    }
}
```

And find() function being called by remove()

```
template <class T1, class T2>
int find(const T1 ar[], int n, const T2& key)
{
  for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
      if(ar[i] == key)
        {
          return i;
        }
    }
  return -1;
}
```

Comment: Is your `removeStu` and `main` in the same file? Or different files?

Comment: Please make [mcve], so anyone could copy-paste it, try to compile it and would get the same errors from your post.

Comment: ```removeStu``` is in the same file as my ```main```, but ```remove``` and ```find``` are in a separate file which I included.

Comment: It seems you have `removeStu` defined after `main` where it's called. Like any name, it has to be declared or defined before it can be used.

Comment: Did you include the template header above the prototype? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46637652/why-doesnt-this-template-function-prototype-work-properly

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I moved my template to a header file and got it to work. Thank you!!